# Java comb sort caught in an infinite loop

Tags: java, sorting

I'm doing a combsort algorithim as a class assignment, and it loops whenever I run it. I'm not sure what I did wrong (I got it working in C++, but that was a while ago, and those skills don't translate as well as I'd like them to). I've been poring over it for an hour and a half now, and emailed some friends, but nobody has any ideas, unfortunately. I think I just need someone with some more experience to tell me what I screwed up. Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CombSort {
    public CombSort()
    {
        super();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> combSort(ArrayList<Integer> sortMe)
    {
        int swap;
        int size = sortMe.size();
        int gap = size;
        boolean swapped = false;

        while ((gap > 1) || swapped)
        {
            if (gap > 1)
            {
                gap = (int) ((size)*((double)gap / 1.247330950103979));
            }

            swapped = false;

            for (int i = 0; gap + i < size; ++i)
            {
                if (sortMe.get(i) - sortMe.get(i + gap) > 0)
                {
                    swap = sortMe.get(i);
                    sortMe.set(i, sortMe.get(i + gap));
                    sortMe.set(i + gap, swap);
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortMe;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> randomArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(7);
        randomArrayList.add(5);
        randomArrayList.add(7);
        randomArrayList.add(2);
        randomArrayList.add(6);
        randomArrayList.add(8);
        randomArrayList.add(2);
        randomArrayList.add(9);
        CombSort combSorter = new CombSort();
        System.out.println(combSorter.combSort(randomArrayList).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you start by debugging your own code to help isolate the cause of the problem. You can do this with your IDE's debugger if you are using one or by sprinkling System.out.println() statements throughout your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `gap` value is getting bigger with each iteration inside the `while` loop, hence why it is infinitely looping.

You should only multiply the gap by the comb factor, not by the size.

`(int) ((size)*((double)gap / 1.247330950103979));` should be

`(int) ((double)gap / 1.247330950103979);`

Comment: Huzzah! Thanks so much, I doubt I would have caught that without another hour's or more worth of work. Also shout-out to Code-Guru because I definitely should have done that before submitting the question.